# New Group (Parent) to Expandable List View in android

Tags: android, expandablelistview

I am developing an Android app in which  have to add new group in `ExpandableListView` at run time. What I am doing is, I have one `EditText` and one `Button`. When user writes in `EditText` and clicks on `Button` that should be added to `ExpandableListView` as new Group(Parent). Here is my code. What needs to be done?

### ExpandableDemo.java

```
 public class ExpandableDemo extends Activity implements OnChildClickListener{

        private ArrayList<String> parentItems = new ArrayList<String>();
        private ArrayList<Object> childItems = new ArrayList<Object>();
        ExpandableListView expandableList;
        String s[]=new String[]{"New List"};
        public static Session friendSession;
        final private static int DIALOG_LOGIN = 1;
        String listData;


        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            // this is not really  necessary as ExpandableListActivity contains an ExpandableList
            setContentView(R.layout.expandable);
            expandableList = (ExpandableListView)findViewById(R.id.listex); // you can use (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.list)
            expandableList.setDividerHeight(2);
            expandableList.setGroupIndicator(null);
            expandableList.setClickable(true);

            setGroupParents();
            setChildData();

            MyExpandableAdapter adapter = new MyExpandableAdapter(parentItems, childItems);

            adapter.setInflater((LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE), this);
            expandableList.setAdapter(adapter);
            expandableList.setOnChildClickListener(this);

            expandableList.setOnGroupClickListener(new OnGroupClickListener()
            {
                  public boolean onGroupClick(ExpandableListView arg0, View arg1, int groupPosition, long arg3) 
                  {
                     // Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "" + groupPosition, 1000).show();

                      if(groupPosition == 0)
                      {
                          showDialog(DIALOG_LOGIN);
                      }
                      else
                      {

                      }
                      return false;
                   }
            });




        }

        public void setGroupParents() {
            parentItems.add("New Friend List");


        }

        public void setChildData() {


            ArrayList<String> child = new ArrayList<String>();
            //child.add("");

            childItems.add(child);


        }

        @Override
        public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,
                int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return false;
        }


          @Override
         protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id)
          {

          AlertDialog dialogDetails = null;

          switch (id)
          {
            case DIALOG_LOGIN:
            LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);
            View dialogview = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog, null);
            AlertDialog.Builder dialogbuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            dialogbuilder.setView(dialogview);
            dialogDetails = dialogbuilder.create();
            break;
          }

          return dialogDetails;
         }

        @Override
         protected void onPrepareDialog(int id, Dialog dialog) {

          switch (id) {
          case DIALOG_LOGIN:
           final AlertDialog alertDialog = (AlertDialog) dialog;
           Button btnOk = (Button) alertDialog.findViewById(R.id.btnOk);
           final EditText etList = (EditText) alertDialog.findViewById(R.id.etList);


           btnOk.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if(etList.length() <= 0)
                {
                    etList.requestFocus();
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Enter Name of List", 1000).show();
                }
                else
                {
                    listData = etList.getText().toString();// This should be name of new group
                        dismissDialog(DIALOG_LOGIN);
                    etList.setText("");
                }
        }
        });

           break;
          }
         }

      }
```

### MyExpandableAdapter.java

```
public class MyExpandableAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

    private Activity activity;
    private ArrayList<Object> childtems;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    private ArrayList<String> parentItems, child;

    public MyExpandableAdapter(ArrayList<String> parents, ArrayList<Object> childern) {
        this.parentItems = parents;
        this.childtems = childern;
    }

    public void setInflater(LayoutInflater inflater, Activity activity) {
        this.inflater = inflater;
        this.activity = activity;
    }

    @Override
    public View getChildView(final int groupPosition, final int childPosition, boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        child = (ArrayList<String>) childtems.get(groupPosition);
        child.get(groupPosition);


        TextView textView = null;

        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.group, null);
        }

        textView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        textView.setText(child.get(childPosition));

        convertView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Toast.makeText(activity, child.get(childPosition),
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });




        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public View getGroupView(final int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded, View convertView, final ViewGroup parent) {



        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row, null);
        }



        if(groupPosition == 0)
        {
            ((CheckedTextView) convertView).setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(R.drawable.add, 0, 0, 0);
            ((CheckedTextView) convertView).setPadding(30, 0, 0, 0);
            ((CheckedTextView) convertView).setText(parentItems.get(groupPosition));
            ((CheckedTextView) convertView).setChecked(isExpanded);
        }
        else
        {
            ((CheckedTextView) convertView).setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(R.drawable.right, 0, 0, 0);
            ((CheckedTextView) convertView).setText(parentItems.get(groupPosition));
            ((CheckedTextView) convertView).setChecked(isExpanded);
            ((CheckedTextView) convertView).setPadding(30, 0, 0, 0);
            if(((CheckedTextView) convertView).isChecked() == true)
            {
                ((CheckedTextView) convertView).setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(R.drawable.down, 0, 0, 0);
            }

        }




        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
        return ((ArrayList<String>) childtems.get(groupPosition)).size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int getGroupCount() {
        return parentItems.size();
    }

    @Override
    public void onGroupCollapsed(int groupPosition) {
        super.onGroupCollapsed(groupPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public void onGroupExpanded(int groupPosition) {
        super.onGroupExpanded(groupPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {

        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasStableIds() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return false;
    }

}
```

Comment: Have got this got succeeded with example/project...